# dtsx package runs by command prompt but not by .bat file

Tags: batch-file, ssis

running a dtsx package by .bat file.

receiving the following error.

Could not load package "C:......dtsx" because of error 0xC0011002.
Failed to open package file "C:......dtsx" due to error 0x800C0006. the system cannot locate the object specified. this occurs when loading a package and the file cannot be opened or loaded correctly into the xml document.

my .bat file is:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTExec" /f C:\..\..\...dtsx
```

however if i run the exact same code by command prompt it runs.

ideas?

Comment: You copy the line from the batch file and paste into a command prompt it works. You, still as you and not another user, double clicks the batch file and it generates that error?

Comment: Yes, It then generates that error when i run the batch file

Comment: Put `C:\..\..\...dtsx` also in double quotes in case of containing a character listed at end on last page of help output in a commmand prompt window after entering `help cmd`.

Comment: I had this same problem, but it was because I wasn't fully qualifying the dtsx path... When I did that, it worked